# Read property bag from a sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a sharepoint 2013 app with asp.net mvc
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bspann/archive/2013/01/19/asp-net-mvc-based-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-on-premises.aspx

The thing is we want to rely on the knowledge of our asp.net developers, and with one sharepoint developer help to help in the integration process.

We dont want to rely on web.config for connectionstrings, but instead on the property bag.
The question is from the sharepoint app, is it possible to read a value in the SPFarm object property bag? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to access things in SharePoint 2013 when making an app (and in many other situations) is through the client side object model (CSOM) API. You can use them through REST endpoints from any server or client side code. For example, you can access the properties of a web through the URL: `http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/allProperties`

Check out this page for a bit more of an intro to using REST.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx

As Dragan pointed out, when coding in .NET technologies you can access the CSOM API through the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client assembly. For more information on that, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't agree 100% with you. In cases when app is based on .NET technology, you should use .NET CSOM to access things in SharePoint, and not REST.